# Exception vs Non exception handling in c style languages

Tags: c++, exception

This question was brought to me because I was watching [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOCElcMcFik)
A large part of the second half of the talk is spent kinda going back and fourth about exception vs non exception handling in c++.

I am working mainly with c but I would like to get some experienced programmers help understanding this.

I haven't written any code that really did anything with exceptions, I have done java code and that basically forces you to add try/ catch blocks etc.

When he says exception handling vs non exception handling does that mean the way java almost forces you to add those blocks around any unsafe code while in c basically if you don't remember to do it your app will just crash?

Comment: C does not support exception handling, so you do not even ahve an option. In which way is this related to C then? Either way, your question is either too broad or attracts mostly opinion based answers. Either concentrate on a **specific** aspect, or try somewhere else, perhaps a forum site.

Comment: Unsafe blocks is a bit of bad wording. Exceptions are there to handle exceptional events--X could happen, but it's not likely--not unsafe actions. Events that need to be handled BUT doing so would increase the complexity of the regular flow of code AND don't happen often enough to be worth handling in the regular flow of code. Consider a block of code with dozens of nested if/elses to handle all of the rare edge cases that *could* crop up. Exceptions may reduce this to a linear flow with those rare edge cases pushed off to an alternate path that only happens if the rare event occurs.

Comment: @Olaf the question might have been a bit broad but it was in fact because I didn't clearly understand the issue and that's exactly why I asked. The guy saying basically if the program runs out of memory he just let it crash instead of having the program limp along makes some sense the way he explains it. The selected answer below made it clear that it's something more specific to OOP which clears up a lot.

Comment: The question alone "let a program crash or catch an exception" is alread far too broad. There are just too many aspects you have to consider - from technical passing safety, commercial to psychological.

Comment: And: Do not add C tag for C++ questions! They are **different languages** (heck, you even better had added Python tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take into consideration that exceptions are usually constructs of Object Oriented programming - That's why Java, C#, C++, etc. often talk about exceptions and try/catch blocks.

In C, this isn't the case. Usually errors need to be caught by the programmer by ways of return values (The C standard uses the errno to keep track of any errors values returned by certain functions).

If something goes really wrong, C will either crash or have an unexpected behaviour - This is where exceptions come in. They are fancier constructs to determine where, how, and why something went wrong.

There is no way of making exceptions in C, but something similar could be done with POSIX signals - though not recommended unless you really know what you are doing. Preferably, use return values to determine when someone goes wrong/right.

Comment: Search the internet for "setjmp" and "longjmp" for assistance with exception handling in C.

Comment: @GrGom thanks a lot, this really cleared things up.